# Unknown Smarty Tag from module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have to fix a Prestashop site made by another team. They did their own navigation menu manager module.

When the template try to render the menu, here is what i get:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "C:\laragon\www\encloque_fresh\themes\en-cloque\header.tpl" on line 105 "{menu key='bloctopmenu' module="blocktopmenu" tpl_container="topmenu" tpl_item="item" max_level=3}" unknown tag "menu" <-- thrown in C:\laragon\www\encloque_fresh\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 105
```

And here is the line

```
<div class="row">
  {menu key='bloctopmenu' module="blocktopmenu" tpl_container="topmenu" tpl_item="item" max_level=3}
</div>
```

Any help ?

Prestashop 1.6.0.9
PHP 5.4

Comment: Are you sure the tag ``menu`` exists ?

Comment: I m not used to smarty template system so i don't even know how to check ^^

Comment: By "navigation menu manager" did you mean "a module" or something else like adding code for Smarty ? I don't know that tag, and googling it return nothing

Comment: Yup that's it. They did a module to manage menu links

Comment: o_o that's a strange way to call a module... Can you show the blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.php file ?

Comment: And are you really sure they developped their own module ? blocktopmenu is the name of a prestashop module....

Comment: I'm afraid that the code is too long. 

Mmmh I ll look in this direction (blocktopmenu)

Answer (score 1):

There is some thinking wrong.

'{menu key='bloctopmenu' module="blocktopmenu" tpl_container="topmenu" tpl_item="item" max_level=3}'

menu is function form tpl in 1.7:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_mainmenu/blob/master/ps_mainmenu.tpl

Probably you need to remove this module, and install original blocktopmenu
https://github.com/PrestaShop/blocktopmenu